# How to install Canon printer driver mg4270 with *.rpm files?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, rpm

I have installed this already through lubuntu printer system settings but I am curious, how do I install *rpm files in linux? it mentions Alien but would this be a wise path to use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried normal official [deb-packages](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg4250.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-994547&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=EN)?

Answer (score 1):

go here https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg4250.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-994525&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=EN and click to download and **SAVE** what will be cnijfilter-mg4200series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz

open a terminal; copy each command below; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mg4200series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz

cd cnijfilter-mg4200series-3.80-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

that should 1) install the drivers and 2) register the printer with lpadmin

(Ubuntu uses debian packages)